# Koa's `ctx.status` not getting sent to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, fetch-api, koa

Here is my simple route:

```
router.post('/getFile', async (ctx) => {
  const fileName = `${ctx.request.body.file}.pdf`;
  const file = fs.createReadStream(fileName); // This file might not exist.

  file.on('error', (err) => {
    ctx.response.status = 500; // This status code doesn't make it to client when there's an error.
  });

  ctx.response.type = 'application/pdf';
  ctx.response.body = file;
});
```

And here is my client code:

```
async function main() {
  const request = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({ file: 'bad-file-name' }),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/pdf'
    }
  };

  const response = await fetch('/getFile', request);
  
  if (!response.ok) {
    console.log(response.status); // This is always 404 when I give a bad file name, even though I set it to 500 above. Why?
  }
}
```

Everything is fine when I send a proper file name, but why is the response status code always `404` even though I set it to `500` in my server code during error? Could it be that the response is already finished sending by the time my code reaches `ctx.response.body = ...` in which case the code in the `.on('error')` isn't doing anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking [at the Koa code](https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/302814e7a3ae214e0791edd9a513db9cba4f9b61/lib/context.js#L139-L140), it has specific handling for `ENOENT` (which is the error that gets thrown when a file doesn't exist):

```
// ENOENT support
if ('ENOENT' == err.code) err.status = 404;
```

From what I can see, you can't change which status code Koa will send back (and, to be fair, sending back a 404 for non-existent files *does* make sense).

However, there's a quick hack: because Koa explicitly checks for `err.code` matching `ENOENT`, if you change that code, you can trick Koa into returning another status code:

```
file.on('error', err => {
  err.code   = 'ENOEXIST'; // a made-up code
  err.status = 500;
});
```

Alternatively, you can first check (using `fs.exists()`, `fs.access()` or `fs.stat()`) to see if the file exists before creating the read stream.

Comment: Oh woops, I assumed that accepting the answer would give you the bounty. Gave it to you now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need try something like this:

```
router.post('/getFile', async (ctx) => {
  const fileName = `${ctx.request.body.file}.pdf`;
  const file = fs.createReadStream(fileName); // This file might not exist.

  file.on('error', (err) => {
    ctx.response.status = 500; // This status code doesn't make it to client when there's an error.
  });

  file.on('close', () => {
    ctx.response.type = 'application/pdf';
    ctx.response.body = file;
  });
});
```